# JAXB Define XML elements with dots

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

I need to create a XML which matches this structure:

```
<OfferPackage Name="aaa">
    <OfferPackage.Offers>
        <OfferCollection Capacity="1">
            <Offer Price="12.34"/>
            <Offer Price="12.34"/>
        </OfferCollection>
    </OfferPackage.Offers>
</OfferPackage>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to achieve this here: `<OfferPackage.Offers>`. How I can get this "dot notation" with just annotations? All I got out looks like this:

```
<OfferPackage Name="aaa">
  <OfferCollection Capacity="1">
    <Offer Price="12.34"/>
    <Offer Price="12.34"/>
  </OfferCollection>
</OfferPackage>
```

This is my current code:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "OfferPackage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferPackage {
    
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    private String name = null;

    @XmlElement( name = "OfferCollection")
    private List<OfferCollection> offers = null;

    @SneakyThrows
    public String toString() {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var marshaller = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(OfferPackage.class)
                .createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(this, sw);

        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Offer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferCollection {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Capacity")
    private Integer capacity = null;

    @XmlElement(name = "Offer")
    private List<Offer> offer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior using the [`@XmlElementWrapper` annotation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html):

> Generates a wrapper element around XML representation. This is primarily intended to be used to produce a wrapper XML element around collections.

In your case, it will look similar to this:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "OfferPackage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferPackage {
    
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    private String name = null;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="OfferPackage.Offers")
    @XmlElement( name = "OfferCollection")
    private List<OfferCollection> offers = null;

    @SneakyThrows
    public String toString() {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var marshaller = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(OfferPackage.class)
                .createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(this, sw);

        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

Other possibility will be to define an intermediate class, `OfferPackageOffers` to wrap the `OfferCollection` `List`::

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "OfferPackage.Offers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferPackageOffers {

  @XmlElement( name = "OfferCollection")
  private List<OfferCollection> offers = null;

  //...
}
```

And use the new class in `OfferPackage` instead of the mentioned `OfferCollection` `List`:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "OfferPackage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OfferPackage {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
  private String name = null;

  @XmlElement( name = "OfferPackage.Offers")
  private OfferPackageOffers offers = null;

  //...

}
```